# How to reset radio buttons and checkboxes in a Bootstrap 4 modal form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

Actually I'm using Boostrap 4 and I want to reset all the inputs inside my form via JS with the function below. All **text inputs** are reseted correctly but the **radio** **buttons** group and **checkboxes** do not get deselected.

```
$('#new_customer')
  .find(':input')
  .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
  .val('')
  .removeAttr('checked')
  .removeAttr('selected');
};
```

I know the original inputs are hidden and styles are build using `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements. But in the documentation I do not see a possible way to reset those controls. How do I achieve this?

Comment: How's my answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51618515/7733026

Answer (score 2):

Use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead

```
$('#new_customer')
  .find(':input')
  .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
  .val('')
  .prop('checked', false)
  .prop('selected', false);
};
```

Comment: Please explain why the OP should use `.prop()` instead, and accompany it with a working example.

Comment: People who view this answer are less likely to be helped by it if you just have a link and some incomplete code.

Comment: James, when I see a question I can answer, I immediately try to get in with the first   answer to get the points before someone else does. (Don't you find it annoying mid answer that someone pips you to it?) If the OP can't read the docs I provided or needs some clarification I am then happy to help

Comment: yes, aside from the closing bracket on the last line, the code works great to clear custom bootstrap 4 input controls.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
$('#new_customer')
  .find(':input')
  .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
  .val('')
  .removeAttr('checked')
  .removeAttr('selected');
};
```

Has an unexpected `};` on the end which will be throwing an error.

If you remove it, your code works fine.

```js
$('#new_customer')
  .find(':input')
  .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
  .val('')
  .removeAttr('checked')
  .removeAttr('selected');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="new_customer">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text" value="text">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <input type="radio">
  <input type="radio" checked>
</div>
```

The usual format for jQuery code is as following:

```
$('#new_customer').find(':input').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden').val('').removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
```